# DRF: request.user returns nothing for token based authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am basically new to DRF & trying to make one API endpoint to update user via mobile app,here is my code for that,

```
class MobileAppUserUpdateView(APIView):
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user

        print('USER',user) #<- prints nothing
        print('TOKEN',request.auth) #<- prints the token
        
        return ResponseBuilder.success([constants.RECORD_UPDATED])
```

there I want to access the user who has made that request using the auth token but getting nothing there.Here is my settings for DRF,

```
NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY = 'message'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
   ),
   'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY,
   
}
```

I have also added the `"rest_framework.authtoken"` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list as per the documentation.Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the users table, User model returns the email for **str** method & the email field had null value that's why I was getting nothing when I try to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Just few things more..

You need to add `authentication_classes` in `MobileAppUserUpdateView` which includes `TokenAuthentication`, like this:

```
class MobileAppUserUpdateView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ...
```

Then make sure you have added `rest_framework.authtoken` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]
```

Then run `manage.py migrate` after changing your settings.

Use a debugger to debug the code and check what your `request` object is receiving.

You can follow this [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) for more.

Comment: Sharme, I have tried to add those classes but still the same issue. Why do I have to add those classes if I have already added those in the default settings?

Comment: This is just another way of setting your authentication scheme.

Comment: I figured it out, request.auth was returning empty string because in the model i had specified to return email but the email had null value in the database.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi please answer your own question and mark it as solved.